# Where did "URL Access Scripting.app" go in Lion?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have AppleScripts that run on a schedule to download files from URLs. They had been using `URL Access Scripting.app`'s `download` event, which now looks to have disappeared from Lion.

I can't find any documentation telling me what happened to it, or what the way forward is. The [AppleScript release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/Introduction/Introduction.html) cover Snow Leopard, but not Lion (not yet, at least), and Mac OS X Automation's [Lion Applescript page](http://www.macosxautomation.com/lion/applescript.html) only mentions new features. Is `URL Access Scripting.app` still hiding someplace, or do I need to find a new way to download a file to disk?

Comment: I just heard about this, and I am using Lion now. Where can I download this tool? It's nowhere on Apple's servers that can find, or in my old Snow Leopard machines.

Comment: @PeterPayne Read the answer already posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple eliminated **URL Access Scripting.app** in Lion for unknown reasons, and obviously hasn't released any documentation on why they did so or workarounds. Additionally, if you copy over the app, it will appear but it still won't work.

Likely the best workaround until documentation is released (although I wouldn't be surprised to see others recommend this) is to change your scripts to use curl. Editing the scripts should be fairly simple, and curl is actually quite reliable and useful.

If you don't know curl, you should be able to figure it out fairly quickly, it's nothing too challenging. Here is an example of a script that was converted (by another user) to curl. My apologies if it isn't exactly the same as your scripts, but you should be able to get a few ideas from the block of code.

```
-- Using URL Access Scripting
set myFile to ((path to temporary items) as string) & "url_access_file.xml"
tell application "URL Access Scripting"
download "http://whateverlink.com" to file myFile
end tell

-- Using curl
set myFile to (POSIX path of (path to temporary items)) & "curl_file.xml"
do shell script "curl -L " & "http://whateverlink.com" & " -o " & myFile
```

Comment: My script downloads images (specifically, see URL http://interfacelift.com/wallpaper/7yz4ma1/02657_yllasjarvi_1920x1200.jpg), and curl isn't working. It doesn't download anything. I'm not sure if I need custom headers, or what's going on...

Comment: It turns out I needed to pass in the -A flag with a user agent string. That looks like: `-A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/534.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.50"`

Comment: That's great that you got this to work in curl!