# How do I download a URL using Applescript

Tags: applescript

I used to be able to download URLs from an Applescript, but I lost the Applescript. I want to enter a URL: i.e.: "http://wpclassic.com/go.php?http://www.revolutiontwo.com/download/tv.zip" and have it prompt for a place to put the file.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18487/where-did-url-access-scripting-app-go-in-lion

Comment: @ghoppe Sort of, but I'm using SL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set the URLs to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter the URLs you would like to download. If you have more than one, separate them with commas please:" default answer "")
set the destination to (choose folder with prompt "Choose the folder you want to download the URLs to:")
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
repeat with this_URL in the URLs
    tell application "URL Access Scripting" to download this_URL to the destination with progress and unpacking
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

If you are using Lion, the above code won't work (Apple removed `URL Access Scripting` for some reason). Use the shell command `curl` instead, as shown below:

```
set the URLs to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter the URLs you would like to download. If you have more than one, separate them with commas please:" default answer "")
set the destination to (choose folder with prompt "Choose the folder you want to download the URLs to:")
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
repeat with this_URL in the URLs
      do shell script "curl -L " & this_URL & " -o " & POSIX path of the destination 
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

Comment: Just so you know...there should be a parenthese on the first line after "default answer""".

Comment: @daviesgeek Wow did not see that. Thanks I will fix it. :)

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: AppleScript Editor gives me: error "URL Access Scripting got an error: Unsupported scheme" number -30774

Comment: I think this worked. I will have to check to see if it did.

Comment: Just before the curl line, I get a syntax error: Expected “end” but found unknown token. Anyone know why?